# Calculating the Difference Between Two Values in two tables using group by in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table as shown below. I want to do a partition and then subtract the values in two tables to get the difference using group by.

Table 1:

| id | type | name | amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | sale | sam | 2 |
| 2 | sale | sam | 15 |
| 3 | sale | lilly | 25 |
| 4 | sale | anju | 20 |

Table 2:

| id | type | name | amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | return | lilly | 20 |
| 2 | return | sam | 3 |
| 2 | return | xyz | 7 |

And Need to return:

| name | amount |
| --- | --- |
| sam | 14 |
| lilly | 5 |
| anju | 20 |
| xyz | -7 |

Comment: Does table 2 only ever have 1 entry per name if there is an entry at all for a name? and are there ever entries in either table which are not present in the other table?

Answer (score 1):

Aggregate sales and returns first, join them via user and subtract one from the other. `COALESCE` is used so that when no return records are found, you get a 0 instead:

```
SELECT sold.name
     , sold.amount AS sold_amount
     , COALESCE(returned.amount, 0) AS returned_amount
     , sold.amount - COALESCE(returned.amount, 0) AS final_sold_amount
  FROM (SELECT name, SUM(amount) AS amount
          FROM sales
         GROUP BY name
     ) sold -- sales aggregated by name
  LEFT OUTER
  JOIN (SELECT name, SUM(amount) AS amount
          FROM returns
         GROUP BY name
     ) returned -- returns aggregated by name
    ON sold.name = returned.name
```

[Working demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2cc893a68ea8818c554553ed1c8d8779)

PS. You don't actually need both aggregates to happen in subqueries - you could for example aggregate the sales in the main query and only the returns in a subquery. I used subqueries for both for easier understanding.

Comment: How its works when the sale table have no records but return table exists data

Comment: What would be the business sense here? It wouldn't work, if you would like to make it work you'd have to use FULL OUTER JOIN between sales and returns.

Comment: Is  full outer join supported by MySQL

Comment: Right you're using MySQL, no full outer join. Given the changed requirements the approach proposed by Sudipta would work though.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done using UNION ALL operation and GROUP BY clause.

```
SELECT NAME,SUM(SALES-RETURN) AS AMOUNT
FROM
(
SELECT NAME,AMOUNT AS SALES,0 AS RETURN
FROM TABLE1
UNION ALL
SELECT NAME,0 AS SALES,AMOUNT AS RETURN
FROM TABL2
) REPORT
GROUP BY NAME
ORDER BY NAME;
```